# Как задать диапазон кодов клавиш?

Tags: c++builder

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer2Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
if (KEYDOWN(32))
{
Событие
}
}
```

Как задать диапазон на месте кода одной клавиши?

Comment: написать что то вида `if (KEYUP(32) | KEYUP(100) | KEYUP(122))`?

Answer (score 1):

Что делает `KEYDOWN`? В гугле не нашел.

Теперь по делу: если нужен именно диапазон, то можно написать вспомогательную функцию, которая пробежит по всему диапазону и выполнит проверку `KEYDOWN` с каждым элементом диапазона:

```
bool KeyDownRange(int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (KEYDOWN(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

И потом в вашей функции:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer2Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (KeDownRange(32, 64)) {
        Событие
    }
}
```

Comment: [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(46): E2141 Declaration syntax error

Comment: [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(55): E2219 Wrong number of arguments in call of macro 'KEYDOWN'

Comment: {
int c;
int w=15;
for( c=0;c<=3;c++){
w++;
if (KEYDOWN(w))
{
Timer1->Enabled = false;
}
}
}   Вот так работает.